# Could a prolonged amount of Antibiotics severely affect the digestion Gut Microbiota?

Tags: antibiotics, microbiome

Could taking antibiotics for a prolonged amount of time severely harm or even worse kill off a large proportion of Gut Microbiota responsible entirely for  digestion, Resulting in lifelong digestion problems similar to Crohn's Disease?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is more suitable for SE Medical Sciences, which did not exist when it was originally posted.